# Including one JSP page into another

Tags: java, xml, xslt, jstl, el

I have a JSP page that includes another HTML page. The latter has the following contents:

```
<html>
<body>
<ul>    

<li>
<a href="/TutorWebApp/page/common/login.jsp">${startPage}</a>
</li>            

</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

This html file is a result xslt transformation from xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testing>
    <menu>
        <menu-item>
            <title>${startPage}</title>
            <url>/TutorWebApp/page/common/login.jsp</url>                        
        </menu-item>
    </menu>
</testing>
```

And with help stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">   

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>            
            <body>                
                <ul>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </ul>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="menu-item">
        <li>
            <a>
                <xsl:attribute name="href">
                    <xsl:value-of select="url"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
            </a>            
        </li>        
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm including the the HTML page by means of using the JSTL's c:import tag ( I use jspf -header and footer and libraries are included in header).

```
<fmt:bundle basename="by.epam.testing.resource.content" prefix="content.">
    <fmt:message key="inputinfo" var="InputInfo"/>    
    <fmt:message key="exit" var="Exit"/>   
    <fmt:message key="startPage" var="StartPage"/>
</fmt:bundle>
<div class="left"> 
    <c:if test="${role eq 'Tutor'}">
        <c:import url="/page/menuForTutor.html" charEncoding="UTF-8"/>
    </c:if>

    <c:if test="${role eq 'Student'}">
        <c:import url="/page/menuForStudent.html" charEncoding="UTF-8"/>
    </c:if>    
</div>
```

The problem is that I'm getting the following output. I.e. the JSP variable names aren't expanded.
[image: screenshot]

Is there any way to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: HTML files are static files, which are not interpreted by the JSP compiler. You can't use the JSP EL in a HTML file. Moreover, a complete HTML page inside another HTML page is invalid HTML.

Comment: Ray, the HTML page within an HTML page is a common mistake for someone new to working with templating in Java. While it might not seem important right now, I strongly encourage you to invest some time in HTML/CSS/JS skills as well. I don't think you need to be an expert at them, but knowing the basics of what's valid in HTML will pay many dividends for you in the long run. Best of luck! :)

Comment: To clarify, you can have a *partial* JSP page inside another, as long as what's generated and visible in the browser source is a resulting, valid, single HTML document.

Comment: @jmort253 Can I use el-expression in included page if I use xslt transformation from xml to jsp?

Comment: @Ray: No (or at least, it would be extremely inefficient): if you keep changing a JSP, the container will have to compile it gain and again. JSPs should not be generated.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet)'s comment:

> HTML files are static files, which are not interpreted by the JSP compiler.
>
> You can't use the JSP EL in a HTML file.
>
> Moreover, a complete HTML page inside another HTML page is invalid HTML.